# Bibtex footnote - citation in beamer have tried many posts

Tags: bibtex, citing, compilation-error

I read through many posts and I cannot for the life of me get this citation working. My bib file is located in the same folder as my LaTeX file and everything is named appropriately.

Please help!

**Update**

I have copied the below answered working code and my citations are still not being generated.

No .blg file created with errors from BibTex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\title{Investigating Consonance and Dissonance}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\date{}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}


\begin{document}
\metroset{block=fill}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]{What is Consonance?} \vspace{10pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item “A tone combination that is stable is called a \textbf{\textit{consonance}}. Consonances are points of arrival, rest, and resolution.” \footcite{kamien2008music}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{10pt}

\end{frame}
```

Here is my bib file

```
@book{kamien2008music,
  title={Music: An Appreciation},
  author={Kamien, R.},
  isbn={9780073526560},
  lccn={2006044401},
  series={Music: An Appreciation},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=58UYAQAAIAAJ},
  year={2008},
  publisher={McGraw-Hill Education}
}
```

**Update**

Errors that came through on the compiler

```
Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                "test for citation"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to '"test for citation".run.xml'.
\openout1 = `"test for citation.run.xml"'.
```

and this

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'kamien2008music' on page 2 undefined on input line 51.


[2

]
\tf@nav=\write7
\openout7 = `"citation test.nav"'.

\tf@toc=\write8
\openout8 = `"citation test.toc"'.

\tf@snm=\write9
\openout9 = `"citation test.snm"'.

 (citation test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `"citation test".out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                "citation test"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to '"citation test".run.xml'.
\openout1 = `"citation test.run.xml"'.

 )
```

some more BibTex

```
(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load BibTeX backend compatibility...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-bibtex.def' found.
(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-bibtex.def
File: blx-bibtex.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)


Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.

)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 (C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count469
\c@textcitetotal=\count470
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count471
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count472
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count473
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count474
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count475
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count476
\biburlbigskip=\muskip18
\biburlnumskip=\muskip19
\biburlucskip=\muskip20
\biburllcskip=\muskip21
\c@smartand=\count477
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'verbose'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'verbose.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\verbose.bbx
File: verbose.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authortitle'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authortitle.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\authortitle
.bbx
File: authortitle.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\standard.bb
x
File: standard.bbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count478
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count479
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'verbose'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'verbose.cbx' found.

(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex/cbx\verbose.cbx
File: verbose.cbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
\@quotelevel=\count480
\@quotereset=\count481
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+jkpss on input line
 35.
 (C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kpfonts\ot1jkpss.fd
File: ot1jkpss.fd 2007/07/16 Fontinst v1.928 font definitions for OT1/jkpss.
)
(citation test.aux)
\openout1 = `"citation test.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/jkp/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+jkp on input line 3
5.
```

Some more Errors

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' specified.
Package biblatex Info: Data encoding 'utf8' specified.
(biblatex)             No need to reencode data.
Package biblatex Info: Document encoding is UTF8 ....
Package biblatex Info: ... and expl3
(biblatex)             2021-11-12 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is new enough (at least 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=expl3'.

(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-case-expl3.
sty
(C:\Users\Maxb\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse
.sty
Package: xparse 2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: blx-case-expl3 2020/12/31 v3.16 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
)
\openout5 = `citation_test-blx.bib'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file '"citation test".bbl' not found.

No file "citation test".bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 35.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 35.
(citation test.nav)
Overfull \vbox (45.50984pt too high) detected at line 40
 []

[1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you get errors by using the characters `“` and `”`. Change them to `''` and ``` `` ```.

Please see the following MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kamien2008music,
  title={Music: An Appreciation},
  author={Kamien, R.},
  isbn={9780073526560},
  lccn={2006044401},
  series={Music: An Appreciation},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=58UYAQAAIAAJ},
  year={2008},
  publisher={McGraw-Hill Education},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\title{Investigating Consonance and Dissonance}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\date{}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\metroset{block=fill}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]{What is Consonance?} \vspace{10pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item ''A tone combination that is stable is called a % <===============
  \textbf{\textit{consonance}}. Consonances are points of arrival, rest, 
  and resolution.``\footcite{kamien2008music} % <=======================
\end{itemize}
\vspace{10pt}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

compiling without errors ...

Comment: this is still not working for me. I have copied what you did exactly.  With the quotes and I even removed the quotes and it's still not working!

Comment: I even created a new document and only copied what you have posted and I get the same error. The compiler is saying using fall-back BibTex(8) backend:(biblatex) functinality may be reduced/unavailable.

Comment: @MaxB "Is not working" is not very helpful ... Which first error message do you get? Copy it from your log file and paste it into your question please.

Comment: Sorry. I added the errors from the log file. I created a new document copied exactly from what you have posted above.

Comment: @MaxB Well your shown "biblatex Warning" is only a warning and no error. I'm having this warning too. Simply follow the usual compiling chain: pdflatex mwe.tex, bibtex mwe, pdflatex mwe.tex, pdflatex mwe.tex ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I've never looked at compiler errors before. Where do i find those files to look at?

Comment: @MaxB If your TeX file is named `mwe.tex` you will find a file `mwe.log` after the first run of `pdflatex mwe.tex`. Check this file for error messages and copy/paste the complete message (including line endings) to your question. Error messages for the bibtex run you can find in the file `mwe.blg`, if you are using my code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I won’t be able to provide feedback until tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131677/discussion-between-max-b-and-mensch).

Comment: I updated the question with some more errors but don't see anything that really sticks out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not building the file with bibtex and only using 'Quick Build' within TexMaker.